# Easiest way to catch the case that for 5 Variables x, y, z, a, b that a and b are equal to either x, y or z

Tags: c++, variables

So for example x=a, y=b would be okay, basically checking whether a and b are Elements of {x,y,z}. For x,y,z,a,b all integers in c++. How would I generally approach such a problem in an elegant way? My current way is a whole lot of if-clauses...

Answer (score 0):

I only see the simpliest approach:

```
if (((a==x) || (a==y) || (a==z)) &&
    ((b==x) || (b==y) || (b==z)))
...
```

It might be interesting to realise that most compilers are optimised, so imagine that `a==x` indeed, the next parts of the `OR`-clause will not be executed, as `true || whatever || whatever` yields `true`.

Obviously, my answer is based on the assumption (as you wrote) that there are only three values (`x`, `y` and `z`) to compare against. In case there are more, like some tens or hundreds or even more, you might put them into a sorted collection and do some binary search, but this falls outside the scope of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort x,y,z and a,b. Then you need to check only three cases: a==x && b==y; a==x && b==z; a==y && b==z; I don't see a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: And what if a==z and b==x?

Comment: You sorted x,y,z and a,b so you know that a <= b and x <= y <= z. If a was equal to z and b equal to x it would mean that x==y==z and you would find the answer in one of the cases we check.

Comment: Maybe so, but sorting takes performance, certainly if you do it in a general way. Put this into some for-loops and the constant sorting might cause major performance holes.